# how to add value (array[i]+1) to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, for-loop, nsmutablearray

i'm from poland so sorry for word mistakes.

what's my problem?

i've got array with representation of red color, its:

```
NSMutableArray *redColor = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 255];
```

i've got FOR loop for fill my array value: 0.

```
for (int i=0; i < 255; i++) {
    [redArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] atIndex:i];
}
```

ok it's fine. but problem is when i want to add value in next FOR loop.

```
for (NSUInteger ii = 0 ; ii < width * height ; ++ii)
{
 //blablabla


[redArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:redArray[ii]+1] atIndex:redArray[ii]];
//example: ii=4
//insertObject: (numberWithInt:value for redArray[4] + 1) at index:4.

//it's not work because i've got ERROR: Subscript requiers size of interface
//"NSMutableArray", which is non constant in non-fragile ABI.
}
```

how i can fix it? i don't know how to easy increment value in NSMutableArray cell.

thanks you for help, it's my first post here.

regards, Tomek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike C/C++, NSArray is not accessed using a [] operator.
To access an element of an NSArray, use objectAtIndex:.

```
[redArray objectAtIndex:ii]
```

Additionally, when you want to add 1 to the element in the array, you must convert the original value back to an int from NSNumber.

```
[[redArray objectAtIndex:ii] intValue] +1
```

Alternatively, you could just use a normal C array.

```
int redArray[255];
redArray[index] = redArray[index] + 1
```

Objective-C is a super-set of C (meaning it contains all of C), so standard C arrays are valid.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There are three problems with your code. First, you cannot access array elements with the subscript syntax. To access objects contained in a `NSArray`, you need to use the `objectAtIndex:` method.

You need to replace:

```
redArray[ii]
```

with:

```
[redArray objectAtIndex:ii]
```

And then you'll get a `NSNumber` instance, with which you can't directly do arithmetic. You'll need to call `intValue` on it first:

```
[[redArray objectAtIndex:ii] intValue] + 1
```

Also, the `atIndex:` parameter of `insertObject:atIndex:` accepts a `NSInteger`, not a `NSNumber`. Therefore, it makes no sense to query the `NSArray`. You will have to replace:

```
redArray[ii]
```

with just:

```
ii
```

This call will insert a new object in the array. In case you meant to replace the previous `NSNumber`, use `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:`.

With all the changes, the line should look like this (I've split it on several lines for the sake of clarity):

```
int red = [[redArray objectAtIndex:ii] intValue] + 1;
NSNumber* redObject = [NSNumber numberWithInt:red];
[redArray insertObject:redObject atIndex:ii];
// or possibly:
// [redArray replaceObjectAtIndex:ii withObject:redObject];
```

Comment: One little correction: `insertObject:atIndex:` is a method (instance method) for `NSMutableArray`, not `NSArray`.